# how to use mouseover textviewer in android

Tags: android, textview, onmouseover

I have a `TextView` where I must display a long text. It must be display on 2 lines (a part of the text) , and the entire text to be display in a a ballon that is displayed "on mouseover". I searched and I did not find anything in this sens in Android.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on mouseover?? or onclick?

Comment: I don't know how it is on android...I think that on onclick or ontouch

Comment: In android where is the mouse? haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this example https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D and it solved my problem.

Comment: I didnt understand the question haha check [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with substring to cut your text when is showed and when is clicked show all. And in the TextView set height=wrap_content.

Example:

```
textView.setText(myString.substring(0,100); //or something like this.

textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(myString);
        }

    });
```

and in the xml:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
```

I didnt check it but I think it will work, but be care with the size of the layouts.